# Mockito Spy quartz MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean target job bean failed

Tags: spring, mockito, awaitility

Spring 6, Quartz, and a SimpleTrigger based scheduled task.

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class Greeting {

    public void sayHello() {
        log.debug("Hello at {}:", LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

Quartz config:

```java
@Configuration
class QuartzConfig{
    @Bean
    MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean greetingJobDetailFactoryBean() {
        var jobFactory = new MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean();
        jobFactory.setTargetBeanName("greeting");
        jobFactory.setTargetMethod("sayHello");
        return jobFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleTriggerFactoryBean simpleTriggerFactoryBean() {
        SimpleTriggerFactoryBean simpleTrigger = new SimpleTriggerFactoryBean();
        simpleTrigger.setJobDetail(greetingJobDetailFactoryBean().getObject());
        simpleTrigger.setStartDelay(1_000);
        simpleTrigger.setRepeatInterval(5_000);
        return simpleTrigger;
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
        var factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        factory.setTriggers(
                simpleTriggerFactoryBean().getObject(),
                cronTriggerFactoryBean().getObject()
        );
        return factory;
    }
```

And I tried to use awaitility to check the invocations.

```java
@SpringJUnitConfig(value = {
        QuartzConfig.class,
        Greeting.class
})
public class GreetingTest {

    @Autowired
    Greeting greeting;

    Greeting greetingSpy;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        this.greetingSpy = spy(greeting);
    }

    @Test
    public void whenWaitTenSecond_thenScheduledIsCalledAtLeastTenTimes() {
        await()
                .atMost(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .untilAsserted(() -> verify(greetingSpy, atLeast(1)).sayHello());
    }
}
```

Running the tests, it is failed.

```bash
org.awaitility.core.ConditionTimeoutException: Assertion condition defined as a com.example.demo.GreetingTest 
Wanted but not invoked:
greeting.sayHello();
-> at com.example.demo.GreetingTest.lambda$whenWaitTenSecond_thenScheduledIsCalledAtLeastTenTimes$0(GreetingTest.java:36)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
 within 10 seconds.
```

In the jobDetailFactorBean, I used `jobFactory.setTargetBeanName("greeting");` to setup the target beans here, it should pass the Greeting bean directly.

**Updated**: resolved myself, check [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring6-sandbox/blob/master/quartz/src/test/java/com/example/demo/GreetingTest.java).

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a spy that in no way interacts with the actual code:

```java
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        this.greetingSpy = spy(greeting);
    }
```

This would have to be injected into the Spring context as a bean and used everywhere, where `greeting` is used. Spring actually provides such functionality: [@SpyBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html).

Instead of autowiring a `greeting` and wrapping it with a spy that does not interact with anything in the context, replace the `@Autowired` with `@SpyBean` annotation. Thanks to that a spy bean will be created and injected within the Spring context:

```java
    @SpyBean
    Greeting greeting;
```

---

I created a commit in [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/blob/73835874/spring-boot-module/src/test/java/io/github/jonarzz/GreetingTest.java#L18), where you can see the whole code - the test passes. I had to add the `cronTriggerFactoryBean()` method to the configuration as it is omitted in your question.

---

If you cannot use Spring Boot, you can create the spy within Spring context yourself using configuration:

```java
static class Config {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    Greeting greeting() {
        return spy(new Greeting());
    }
}
```

Thanks to that when you inject the bean, it will be possible to act on it with Mockito (remember to include the `Config` class in the `@SpringJUnitConfig` annotation).

I created another commit [in the GitHub repository](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/blob/73835874/spring-boot-module/src/test/java/io/github/jonarzz/GreetingTest.java#L19) - the test passes. You can see the whole code there.

Comment: I do not use Spring Boot here. I know well about the MockBean and SpyBean in Spring Boot.

Comment: I edited the answer and added a solution for this case as well.

Comment: Already resolved myself, check [the tests](https://github.com/hantsy/spring6-sandbox/blob/master/quartz/src/test/java/com/example/demo/GreetingTest.java). BTW, your spy bean does not spy the target bean.

Comment: If the answer is a proper solution to the problem, accept it. No need to spy a specific instance in this case as only the number of invocations is verified.